# Running resolutions script during postinstall doesn't updates package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently, I am working with Angular version 8.0.2, and I'm addressing the project's vulnerabilities using resolutions. To enforce the resolution changes, I've added a postinstall script in my package.json file as follows:

`"postinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"`

The intention is for the script to run automatically after executing the `"npm i --force"` command, which installs the node_modules. However, I've noticed that the package versions specified in the resolutions are not being reflected in the package-lock.json file.

I attempted to remove the node_modules folder from the project by running `rimraf node_modules` and then reinstalled the packages. During the initial installation, only 8 vulnerabilities were reported when running `npm audit`, but I noticed that the package versions were not being updated in the package-lock.json file.

Strangely, when I repeated the same process again, it now shows over 380 vulnerabilities.

My expectation is that when I simply run the `npm i --force` command to install the packages, the postinstall script should execute, and the package versions specified in the resolutions field should be applied to the package-lock.json file.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to address this issue.